# Error: Fixture could not be loaded: fixtures/test.html (status: error, message: undefined)

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

i am trying to use loadFixtures() on my test [jasmine] with karma but it's not working. i am using ' test/fixtures ' as my fixtures dir
i am trying to get 'html' files to load as fixture 
**i am using typescript**

my jasmine unit

```
beforeEach(()=>{
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'fixtures';
    loadFixtures('test.html');
})
```

and the packages are

```
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
"jasmine": "^2.4.1",
"jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
"karma": "^1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-fixture": "^0.2.6",
"karma-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-jquery": "^0.1.1",
"merge2": "^1.0.2"
```

}
now come to karma config file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
```

config.set({

```
// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: 
  [
    'jasmine-jquery',
    'jasmine',
    'fixture'
  ],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  './bin/test/**/*.js',
  './dest/**/*.js',
    {
      pattern: './test/fixtures/*.html',
      watched: true,
      served: true,
      included: false
    }
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
```

})
}

Comment: what is the error that you get? Did you see a 404 error? A suggestions try adding "base/" in front of your fixture path.

Comment: ya i got that. i have already solved that issue . thanks for replaying